# how to plot usmap in R for the ProviderPerFFS in us states given a condition column "Year" in 2016

Tags: r

I was able to plot ProviderPerFFS using usmap package when I did not stack my 2017 dataset:

```
plot_usmap(data = df2, values = "ProviderPerFFS", color = "red") + 
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "ProviderPerFFS10k(2016)", type = "viridis", label = scales::comma) + 
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

Now I have a new column saying the year of 2017 or 2016. I want to graph the usmap separately by the year of 2017 and 2016. I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset or filter your data by the year you want to plot via `subset` or `dplyr::filter` or ... or use facetting if you want plot both years in one plot.

Using some random example data try this:

```r
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

# example data
set.seed(42)
df <- usmapdata::fips_data(regions = "counties") %>%
  select(fips)
df <- list(
  `2016` = mutate(df, ProviderPerFFS = rnorm(nrow(df))),
  `2017` = mutate(df, ProviderPerFFS = rnorm(nrow(df)))
) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "Year")

# Single year
plot_usmap(
  data = subset(df, Year == 2016),
  values = "ProviderPerFFS", color = "red"
) +
  scale_fill_continuous(
    name = "ProviderPerFFS10k(2016)",
    type = "viridis", label = scales::comma
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[image]

```r
# Facet by year
plot_usmap(data = df, values = "ProviderPerFFS", color = "red") +
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "ProviderPerFFS10k(2016)", type = "viridis", label = scales::comma) +
  theme(legend.position = "right") +
  facet_wrap(~Year)
```

[image]

Comment: This is beyond my expectation, appreciate you a bunch!